# jQuery mobile: links have improper format on first load?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I'm learning JQM and `Backbone.js` and I have a few problems. Im making a recipe app following the TODO list example trying to blend them both.

Anyway I can't refresh any page besides the first one, I'm getting undefined variables. I believe it has to do with the DOM and many views I have. Secondly Upon entering the recipe to search for to query the API, it displays the results first as plain links!

If I got forward a page or back a page and return to the results page it display the links as they should be the JQM style. This is because I couldn't figure how or what to append to in the JS, so I did it in the HTML.

I know this is a long shot but can anyone give me guidance as to what the hell I'm doing wrong, general advice, anything?

```
    var Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function() {
      return {
    id: 0,
    title: 'defaultname',
    imgUrl: 'defaultimageurl',
        order: searchTemp.nextOrder(),
        rating: 0,
        timeToMake: '',
        salty: 0,
        sour: 0,
        sweet: 0,
        bitter: 0,  
        isPerm: false,
    taggedForList: false
      };
    },      
    initialize: function(){
      if( !this.get('ingrs') ){ 
        this.set({ingrs: new Array()});
      }
    },
    saveModel: function() {
    this.set({isPerm: true});
    this.save();
    }
});

var TodoList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Todo,
  localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("searchTemp"),
  initialize: function() {
  },
  nextOrder: function() {
    if (!this.length) return 1;
    return this.last().get('order') + 1;
  },
  comparator: 'order',
  taggedForList: function() {
      return this.where({taggedForList: true});
  },
  remaining: function() {
      return this.without.apply(this, this.taggedForList);
  },

  findRecipes: function(theQuery) {
    console.log("findRecipes called");
    searchTemp.each(function (model) {
    if (!model.isPerm) {
        model.destroy();
    }
    });
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipes?_app_id=d8087d51&_app_key=005af5a16f1a8abf63660c2c784ab65f&maxResult=5&q='+theQuery,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(apiStuff){
    var result = new Array();     
    result = apiStuff;          //saves the API's response as a new array
        result = result.matches;    //trims extra information from the json object, now only has information on the various recipes

    $.each(result, function(i, item) {
      var anotherRecipe= new Todo();    // makes a new model for each result

      anotherRecipe.set({
        id: result[i].id,            //then sets the attributes
        title: result[i].recipeName,    
        ingrs: result[i].ingredients,
        imgUrl: result[i].smallImageUrls,
            rating: result[i].rating,
            timeToMake: result[i].totalTimeInSeconds,
          });
          //not all recipes support flavor ratings, so error catching must be used to avoid setting null values
          try { anotherRecipe.set({ salty : result[i].flavors.salty }); } catch(e) {anotherRecipe.set({salty : "?"});}  //maybe replace the error condition to setting the flavor to '?'
          try { anotherRecipe.set({ sour: result[i].flavors.sour }); } catch(e) {anotherRecipe.set({sour : "?"});}
          try { anotherRecipe.set({ sweet: result[i].flavors.sweet }); } catch(e) {anotherRecipe.set({sweet : "?"});}
          try { anotherRecipe.set({ bitter: result[i].flavors.bitter }); } catch(e) {anotherRecipe.set({bitter : "?"});}

      searchTemp.add(anotherRecipe);    //adds the model to the temporary     
    });
      }  //eventually, should add something that checks for an empty search result, appending some warning if that happens
    });
    // console.log("search done");
  }  
});


var ShopItem = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function() {
        return {
            ingr : 'ingredient',
            done : false
        }
    },
    toggle: function() {
      this.save({taggedForList: !this.get("taggedForList")}); 
    }
});

var ShopList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("grocery-list"),
    generate: function() {
    console.log("SHOP LIST!  ASSSSSEMMMMBLLLLLLE!");
    searchTemp.fetch();
    var ingrList = searchTemp.pluck('ingrs');  //this returns an array of arrays
    console.log(ingrList);
    ingrList = _.union(ingrList);   //this needs to get a series of arrays ( _.union(array1, array 2); )
    console.log(ingrList);
    },

    getList: function() {
        var list = new Array();
        list = this.toJSON();
        return list;
    }
});

var Todos = new TodoList;   //I am afraid to move this, 95% sure its obsolete, though
/*
var savedRecipesView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName:  "li",
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'destroy', this.remove);
    },
    render: function() {
        var template = _.template( $("#list_item").html(), {} );
        this.$el.html( template );

        //this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        //this.$el.toggleClass('done', this.model.get('done'));
        //this.input = this.$('.edit');
        //return this;

    },
    events: {
        "click input[type=button]": "sendToGroceries"
    },
    sendToGroceries: function() {
        var temp = new Array();
        temp = this.toJSON();
        $.each(temp, function(i, item) {
            var shopItem = new ShopItem();    
            shopItem.set({ name: temp[i].title });
            shoppingList.add(shopItem); //use pluck [ingrs]
            shopItem.save();
        });    
    }
});
*/
window.HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template:_.template($('#home').html()),

    render:function (eventName) {
        $(this.el).html(this.template());
        return this;
    }
});

window.newSearchView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template:_.template($('#newSearch').html()),
    //this VAGUELY works, but causes visual chaos the first run through,
    //still relies on the appending for that
    initialize: function() {
        console.log(searchTemp);
        //searchTemp.bind('searchDone', this.render, this);
        searchTemp.bind('add', this.render, this);
    },
    render:function (eventName) {

        var temp = new Array();  // I think this line isnt doing anyting
        results = searchTemp.toJSON();
        // console.log(results);
        var variables = {
            recipes: results
        };
        $(this.el).html(this.template());
        return this;
    },
    events: {
      "keypress #recipe-search":  "searchOnEnter",
      //add a listener to newSearch to change what's displaye don this list
    },
    searchOnEnter: function(e) {   //the search bar's functionality
      if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
      var searchin = $("input[id='recipe-search']").val();

      console.log("searched for - "+ searchin);
      //this function is in todoList, does an API call and
      //adds a new model for each result (there will almost always be 5 results)
      searchTemp.findRecipes(searchin);

    }
});

window.newListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template : _.template($('#newList').html()),
    initialize: function() {
    },
    render:function (eventName) {
        recipe = this.model.toJSON(); ///INCOMPLETE, modify newlist to accept straight from JSON
    var variables = {
            recipe_name : this.model.get("title"),
            img_url : this.model.get("imgUrl"),
            timetomake: this.model.get("timeToMake"),
            ingrs : this.model.get("ingrs"),
            rating : this.model.get("rating"),
            salty : this.model.get("salty"),
            sour : this.model.get("sour"),
            sweet : this.model.get("sweet"),
            bitter : this.model.get("bitter")
        };
        $(this.el).html(this.template(variables));
        return this;
    },
    events: {
      "click #save-this":  "saveModel"
    },
    saveModel: function() {
    console.log("saveModel() called");
    //console.log(permStorage.taggedForList());
        //shift the model over to permStorage
        //searchTemp.remove(this.model);
        //console.log(this.model);
        this.model.saveModel();
    //console.log(this.model)
        //now save permStorage to local storage
        searchTemp.each(function (model) {
        if(model.isPerm) {
        model.save();
        }
    });
    }
});

window.savedRecipesView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template:_.template($('#savedRecipes').html()),
    initialize: function() {
    console.log("about to fetch from local storage...");
    searchTemp.fetch();
    console.log("...fetched!");
    },
    render:function (data) {    
        results = searchTemp.toJSON();
    //results = results.models;
    //console.log(results);
        var variables = {
            results: results
        };
    _.each(data, function(task) {
            console.log("meow");
            this.addOne(task);
        }, this);
    $(this.el).html(this.template(variables));
        return this;
    },
    addOne: function(task) {
        var view = new listItemView({ model:task });
        $(this.el).append( view.render().el );
    }
});

window.listItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    template:_.template($('#list-item').html()),
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.model.bind('change', this.render);
        this.model.view = this;
    },
    events: {
        "click input[type=button]" : "onClick"
    },
    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        this.setContent();
        return this;
    },
    onClick: function(){
        searchTemp.add(this.model);
        console.log("model added to searchTemp, current state of searchTemp:");
        console.log(searchTemp);
    }
});

window.oldListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template:_.template($('#oldList').html()), 
    render: function (eventName) {
        $(this.el).html(this.template());
        return this;
    }
});    

window.deleteOldView =  Backbone.View.extend({
    template:_.template($('#deleteOld').html()), 
    render: function (eventName) {
        $(this.el).html(this.template());
        return this;
    }
});

window.shoppingListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template:_.template($('#shoppingList').html()),
    initialize: function() {
    shopList.generate();
    },

    render: function (eventName) {
    var variables = {


    };
    $(this.el).html(this.template(variables));
    return this;
    }

});

var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes:{
        "":"home",
        "newSearch":"newSearch",
        "newList/:id":"newList",
        "savedRecipes":"savedRecipes",
        "oldList":"oldList",
    "deleteOld":"deleteOld",
    "shoppingList":"shoppingList"
    },
    initialize:function () {
        // Handle back button throughout the application
        $('.back').live('click', function(event) {
            window.history.back();
            return false;
        });
        this.firstPage = true;
    },
    home:function () {
        this.changePage(new HomeView());
    },
    newSearch:function () {
        this.changePage(new newSearchView());
    },
    newList:function (theID) {
        var tempModel = searchTemp.get(theID);
        this.changePage(new newListView({
            model: tempModel,
            id: theID
        }));
        //console.log(permStorage.taggedForList());
    },
    savedRecipes:function () {  
        this.changePage(new savedRecipesView());      
    },
    oldList:function () {
        this.changePage(new oldListView());
    },
    deleteOld:function () {
        this.changePage(new deleteOldView());
    },
    shoppingList:function () {
    this.changePage(new shoppingListView());
    },
    changePage:function (page) {
        $(page.el).attr('data-role', 'page');
        page.render();
        $('body').append($(page.el));
        var transition = $.mobile.defaultPageTransition;
        // We don't want to slide the first page
        if (this.firstPage) {
            transition = 'none';
            this.firstPage = false;
        }
        $.mobile.changePage($(page.el), {changeHash:false, transition: transition});
    }

});

$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('document ready');
    app = new AppRouter();
    Backbone.history.start();
    searchTemp = new TodoList(); //this stores searched recipes, rename to myRecipes
    shopList = new ShopList();
});




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="ui-mobile-rendering">
<head>
    <title>RECILIST</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css"/>

    <!-- The Templates -->
    <script type="text/template" id="home">  
         <div data-role="header"  >
            <h1 style="color:black">Recilist Home</h1>
                </div>
                 <img src="store.jpg" id="vege">

        <div data-role="content" style="color:red">
            <!-- <h3>recilist home page</h3>
                 <p>Welcome to Recilist!</p>
                <p>This is the Home page. </p>
                -->
            <h1>Save Recipes & <br/>
            Create Shopping <br/>
             Lists Anywhere</h1>
            <p class="blurb">Create and manage your grocery shopping list, FIND and <br/>SAVE your favorite recipes from across the web,<br/> get great SAVINGS and share with your entire family - for FREEEE!!!!</p>


            <ul data-role="listview" id="choices" data-inset="true">
                <li><a style="color:red" href="#newSearch">Search for new Recipes</a></li>
                <li><a style="color:red" href="#savedRecipes">View saved Recipes</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" class="ui-bar" id ="footer">
            <h5 style="color:black"> powered by <img src="http://static.yummly.com/api-logo.png"> </h5>
        </div>
    </script>

    <script type="text/template" id="newSearch">  
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1 style="color:black">Search for a new Recipe</h1> 
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <input name= "recipe-search" id="recipe-search" data-icon="search" type="text" placeholder="What do you want to cook?">
            <ul id="search-list" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
              <% for(var i in results) { %>
                <li> <img src="<%= results[i].imgUrl %>"> <a href="#newList/<%= results[i].id%>"><%= results[i].title %> </a> </li>
              <% } %> 
            </ul>
        </div>
        <img src="list.png" id="list">
        <div data-role="footer" class="ui-bar">
            <a href="#" data-icon="back" class="back ui-btn-left">Back</a>
            <a href="#" data-icon="home">Home</a>
        </div>
    </script>

    <script type="text/template" id="newList">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1 style="color:black"> <%=recipe_name%> </h1>
        </div>

        <div>
        <div data-role="content">
          <img src= <%=img_url%> >
          <h4>Recipe Rating: <%= rating %> </h4>
          <h4>Total time to Prepare: <%= timetomake %> </h4>
          <h4>Flavor Ratings</h4>
          <div class="ui-block-a"> <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e"> <h4>saltiness</h4> <%= salty %> </div> </div>
          <div class="ui-block-b"> <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e"> <h4>sourness</h4> <%= sour %> </div> </div>
          <div class="ui-block-c"> <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e"> <h4>sweetness</h4> <%= sweet %> </div> </div>
          <div class="ui-block-d"> <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e"> <h4>bitterness</h4> <%= bitter %> </div> </div>            
        </div>

        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
          <h3>Ingredients</h3>
            <ul id="ingr-list" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
              <% for(var i in ingrs) { %>
                <li><%= ingrs[i] %></li>
              <% } %>
            </ul>
        </div>


        <div data-role="content">
          <input type="button" id="save-this" data-icon="check" value="save to My Recipies">
          <div>
           <img src="store3.jpg" id="aisle">
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" class="ui-bar">
            <a href="#" data-icon="back" class="back ui-btn-left">Back</a>
            <a href="#" data-icon="home">Home</a>
        </div>
    </script>

    <script type="text/template" id="savedRecipes">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>My Recipes</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <p>list of saved recipes, retrieved from local storage</p>
            <p>Saved Recipes:</p>
            <ul id="search-list" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
              <% for(var i in results) { %>
                <li> <img src="<%= results[i].imgUrl %>"> <a href="#newList/<%= results[i].id%>"><%= results[i].title %> </a> </li>
              <% } %> 
            </ul>
           <a href="#deleteOld" data-role="button">manage saved recipes</a>
           <a href="#shoppingList" data-role="button">generate shopping list</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" class="ui-bar">
            <a href="#" data-icon="back" class="back ui-btn-left">Back</a>
            <a href="#" data-icon="home">Home</a>
        </div>
    </script>

    <script type="text/template" id="deleteOld">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Delete Recipes</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <p>select which recipes you wish to delete from local storage</p>
            <p>recipes:</p>
            <p>(currently lacks functionality to populate this list)</p>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="recipe-list">

            </ul>
            <input type="button" data-icon="delete" value="delete selected" />
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" class="ui-bar">
            <a href="#" data-icon="back" class="back ui-btn-left">Back</a>
            <a href="#" data-icon="home">Home</a>
        </div>
    </script>


    <script type="text/template" id="oldList">
      <div data-role="header">
          <h1>---NAME OF THE RECIPE----</h1> 
      </div>

      <div data-role="content">
          <p>This is a list of all the ingredients in this recipe</p>
          <p>Ingredients:</p>
          <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
              <li>ingredient 1</li>
              <li>ingredient 2</li>
              <li>ingredient 3</li>
              <li>ingredient 4</li>
          </ul>
          <p> (button to view the recipe) </p>
      </div>

      <div data-role="footer" class="ui-bar">
          <a href="#" data-icon="back" class="back ui-btn-left">Back</a>
          <a href="#" data-icon="home">Home</a>
      </div>
    </script>

    <script type="text/template" id="shoppingList">
      <div data-role="header">
          <h1>shopping list</h1> 
      </div>

      <div data-role="content">
        <ul id="search-list" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
          <% for(var i in results) { %>
            <li> <input type="checkbox" name=i id=i class="custom" /></li>  <!-- these checkboxes are HIDEOUSLY DEFORMED-->
            <label for=i> <%= results[i].title %> </label>
          <% } %> 
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div data-role="footer" class="ui-bar">
          <a href="#" data-icon="back" class="back ui-btn-left">Back</a>
          <a href="#" data-icon="home">Home</a>
      </div>      
    </script>


    <script type="text/template" id="list-item">
      <li>cheese</li>
    </script>
  <!--      <li> <img src= <%=img_url%> > <a href="#newList/"+ <%=model_id%> +"' class='ui-link-inherit'>" + <%=model_title%> + "</a> </li> -->


    <!-- The Scripts -->
    <script src="lib/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jqm-config.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/backbone-min.js"></script>    
    <script src="js/backbone.localStorage.js"</script>
    <script src="js/json2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body></body>

</html>
```

Comment: For list view enhancement `$('data-role=listview]').listview('create');`

Comment: what do you mean 'enhancement'

Comment: To get styled by jQuery Mobile. http://api.jquerymobile.com/listview/ you said you don't see the links unless you leave the page and get back to it. Once you leave the page and return, the links are enhanced. When you create them dynamically, you need to force the enhancement.

Comment: OH reallly !!!! lemme give that a shot & thats exactly what im going through

Comment: Sorry, I missed `[` in my first comment. `$('[data-role=listview]').listview('create');`

Comment: I caught that no problem. I added this a no such method 'create' for listview error widget jquerymobile ...

Comment: No cigar, but i could just be placing it in the wrong place..UGHHH

Comment: GOT IT !! SHOULD BE INCLUDED IN THE AJAX REQUEST THANK YOU sooooooo MUCH !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enhance dynamically created list view, you need to refresh the markup using the below.

```
$('[data-role=listview]').listview('refresh');
```

Comment: Thank you Omar, I've been fighting with this since yesterday and now i can continue my progress. (SHAKES HAND FIRMLY)!